# How Do Spaceships Communicate on First Contact?

Tags: star-trek

While this is mainly from a Star Trek perspective, it could apply to other universes in SF as well (and even to our reality, really).

In [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10881/in-the-new-star-trek-movie-how-could-neros-ship-communicate-with-a-ship-decade) the focus is on ships from 150 years apart communicating.  But one comment there raises a bigger question.

If two ships are approaching each other in space, and they have never contacted each other before and have no knowledge of each other, how would they communicate with each other?  I know if they know some of the same other races, they might have common protocols, but if there was no prior contact at all and no connections at all, how would they communicate with each other?

Comment: Narrative convenience.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Encountering species with incompatible communications protocols is an integral part of interstellar exploration, so every species engaging in it would have developed at least some form of **self-describing protocols**.

We on Earth haven't even achieve interplanetary travel, yet there is already a branch of SETI called [CETI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_with_extraterrestrial_intelligence) (Communication with Extra-Terrestrial Intelligence) that attempts this. The idea is to use universally understood notions (such as numbers, prime numbers, atomic weights, well known spectral wavelengths) to communicate or built a common vocabulary.

We can safely assume that a species advanced enough to build a warp capable starship will also be able to develop a self-describing (or bootstrapping) communications protocol.

On the flip side, they will also have developed automatic protocol analyzers that can take an unknown protocol (even one that is not self-describing) and perform a [statistical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_machine_translation) to derive the protocol being used. Believe it or not, this is pretty much what *Google Translate* does!

**So in summary:**

1. Self-describing (or bootstrapping) communications protocols on the sending side
2. Automatic protocol discovery and conversion on the receiving side

Comment: Of course there are times when it doesn't work: [*Darmok*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darmok).

Comment: *Sokath, his eyes open!*

Comment: And then there are times when this works [WAY too well for suspension of disbelief](http://qntm.org/id4)

Comment: @DVK Seriously...he took down an alien armada with Xcode? And that was a PowerMac...not even Intel based.

Comment: @MikeBrown No, he took down an alien armada with CodeWarrior. ID4 was WAY pre-OSX.

Comment: Oh I thought XCode was around pre OSX. I remember back when there was no such thing as a free Java IDE. Codewarrior was one of the front runners back then. Their palm os suite was pretty good too.

Comment: But doesn't a self describing protocol require some way to create a basic understanding first?

Comment: @TangoOversway That's where the universal notions come in. For example, the sequence 1,2,3,5,7,11,13,... encoded into a radio signal can be recognized as prime numbers and will allow the receiver to work out the encoding with not much difficulty. There are various other methods based on mathematics, chemistry and physical constants.

Comment: @MikeBrown and remember, they had their hands on the tech since the 40's.  Even though they couldn't get it to turn on they probably could piece together a hardware spec.  Who knows, maybe the PowerPC was derivative of the alien hardware.

Comment: @TysonoftheNorthwest like the men in black...that's how we made the huge jump from vacuum tubes to silicon ;)